# Can't select Lucida Sans Typewriter as font for Konsole

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, konsole

I have Lucida Sans Typewriter font installed in my KDE and I can easily use it as text font in my Eclipse. However, this font isn't shown in monospaced fonts list when I am selecting a font for Konsole or in systemsettings.

It is possible, of course, to edit `~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/Shell.profile` and `~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals`, but is there another way? By the way, why the system does not recognize Lucida Sans Typewriter as monospaced font?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How did you install the font ?

Here:

Donwloading the Lucida Sans Typewriter Regular font file (LTYPE.TTF) from the net.

System Settings > System Administration: Font Installer; Add.

The Lucinda Sans Typewriter is under the Personal Fonts.

[image]

And it is available for the Konsole.

[image]